# csrf error while trying to delete an object with ajax

Tags: django, ajax

I have all the objects from my db rendered on my template by an ajax function.
Near every object there's a button that should delete it from the db but since I'm working on Django it raise a csrf_token missing or incorrect error.
I'm not using a form so I don't know how to include the csrf_token.

```js
var $orders = $('#orders')
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/MyApp/list-api/?format=json',
        success: function(orders) {
            $.each(orders, function(i, order){
                $orders.append('<li>name: '+order.name+', drink: 
                               '+order.drink+'</li>')
                $orders.append("<button data-id=" +(order.pk)+" 
                               class='remove'>X</button>")
            });
        },
        error: function() {
        alert('errore caricamento ordini');
        }
    });
    $orders.delegate('.remove', 'click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/MyApp/list-api/' + 
                  $(this).attr('data-id')
        });
    });
```

When I press a remove button a new request appears in the network panel of the browser, the response states :detail: "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect." The console gives a 403 forbidden error.
Any help or hints are really appreciated.

Comment: you have to prepare the requests to make an ajax call when csrf is activated, check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly, I still can't orientate myself in the immense django doc.

Comment: you're welcome! Step by step, needs by needs, topic by topic... :p API ref is a good way https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/